# How to merge and filter two arrays of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, merge

I have the following:

```
var owners = [{
  "ownerid": "11",
  "name": "jane",
  "sex": "female"
}, {
  "ownerid": "22",
  "name": "mike",
  "sex": "male"
}, {
  "ownerid": "33",
  "name": "alex",
  "sex": "male"
}];

var cars = [{
  "ownerid": "11",
  "make": "ford",
  "model": "mustang"
}, {
  "ownerid": "11",
  "make": "honda",
  "model": "civic"
}, {
  "ownerid": "33",
  "make": "toyota",
  "model": "corolla"
}];
```

And I would like to end up with this

```
var mergedandfiltered = [{
  "name": "jane",
  "sex": "female",
  "make": "ford",
  "model": "mustang"
}, {
  "name": "jane",
  "sex": "female",
  "make": "honda",
  "model": "civic"
}, {
  "name": "alex",
  "sex": "male",
  "make": "toyota",
  "model": "corolla"
}];
```

The idea is to have a result merged and filtered so I have a list of owners, owner properties and the cars they own and car properties. Mike doesn't own any cars so doesn't show in the result. "ownerid" is the common link but I don't need it showing in the result.

Pure JS solution prefered please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask) Where are you stuck? The culture on SO is that you should at least make an attempt, and then if you run into issues doing that, show the attempt and describe the issues.

Comment: Basically, all you should need to do is loop over `cars` and find the entry in owners that matches the `ownerid` and then build the new object. Take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and all the available functions for arrays and you should be able to do it. The `map` function would probably be a good place to start since you are mapping one array (the `cars`) to a new array. Then also look at `find` to look up elements in `owners`. It might be more efficient to transform owners into a dictionary keyed on the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First build an object for the reference to the owners, and then iterate over the cars, and combine a new object.

```js
var owners = [{ "ownerid": "11", "name": "jane", "sex": "female" }, { "ownerid": "22", "name": "mike", "sex": "male" }, { "ownerid": "33", "name": "alex", "sex": "male" }],
    cars = [{ "ownerid": "11", "make": "ford", "model": "mustang" }, { "ownerid": "11", "make": "honda", "model": "civic" }, { "ownerid": "33", "make": "toyota", "model": "corolla" }],
    obj = {},
    result;

owners.forEach(function (a) {
    obj[a.ownerid] = a;
});

result = cars.map(function (a) {
    return {
        name: obj[a.ownerid].name,
        sex: obj[a.ownerid].sex,
        make: a.make,
        model: a.model
    };
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var owners = [{"ownerid":"11", "name":"jane", "sex":"female"}, {"ownerid":"22", "name":"mike", "sex":"male"}, {"ownerid":"33", "name":"alex", "sex":"male"}];

var cars = [{"ownerid":"11", "make":"ford", "model":"mustang"}, {"ownerid":"11", "make":"honda", "model":"civic"}, {"ownerid":"33", "make":"toyota", "model":"corolla"} ];

var mergedandfiltered = [];
for(var i = 0; i < owners.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < cars.length; j++){
    if(owners[i]['ownerid'] == cars[j]['ownerid']){
        mergedandfiltered.push({"name":owners[i]['name'],"sex":owners[i]['sex'],"make":cars[j]['make'],"model":cars[j]['model']});
    }        
  }  
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best approach: you will have owners.length * cars.length iterations. Example: if owners has 20 items and cars, 22, the code will iterate 440 times.

Answer (score 2):

For efficiency, we start by transforming our list of users into a dictionary using owner as a key. We can use [Array.protoype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do this:

```
var ownerDict = owners.reduce(function(p, c) {
  p[c.ownerid] = c;
  return p;
}, {});
```

This will give you an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "11": {
        "ownerid": "11",
        "name": "jane",
        "sex": "female"
    },
    "22": {
        "ownerid": "22",
        "name": "mike",
        "sex": "male"
    },
    "33": {
        "ownerid": "33",
        "name": "alex",
        "sex": "male"
    }
}
```

The reason we do this is because now we can look up users with, for example:

```
var owner = ownerDict[11];
```

and this will give you back the object:

```
{
    "ownerid": "11",
    "name": "jane",
    "sex": "female"
}
```

And that look up is `O(1)`. If you have to actually search the array to find it, assuming it's not already sorted, your search would be `O(n)` (if it is sorted, which you example data actually appears to be, it's only slightly better - you *could* use a binary tree search which is `O(log(n))`, but that's still slower than `O(1)` and the code is more complicated.)

Now with that dictionary, we can now just use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform our `cars` array into what you want like this:

```
var mergedandfiltered = cars.map(function(c) {
  var owner = ownerDict[c.ownerid];
  return {
    name: owner.name,
    sex: owner.sex,
    make: c.make,
    model: c.model
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mergedandfiltered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < owners.length; i++) {
    var oID = owners[i].ownerid;
    for (var j = 0; j < cars.length; j++) {
      var mitem = {};
      cID = cars[j].ownerid;
      if (oID==cID) {
        mitem.name = owners[i].name;
        mitem.sex = owners[i].sex;
        mitem.make = cars[j].make;
        mitem.model = cars[j].model;
        mergedandfiltered.push(mitem);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your owners array into a "hash" (using owner as key) and then get their properties based on ownerid from cars' array.

```
var hashowners = [];
owners.forEach(function(o) {
   hashowners[o.ownerid] = {"name": o.name, "sex": o.sex};
});

var finalcars = cars.map( function(car) {
    car.name = hashowners[car.ownerid].name;
    car.sex = hashowners[car.ownerid].sex;
    delete car.ownerid;
    return car;
});

console.log(finalcars)
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/61fb13n8/

Answer (score 0):

```
var owners = [ {
        "ownerid" : "11",
    "name" : "jane",
    "sex" : "female"
}, {
    "ownerid" : "22",
    "name" : "mike",
    "sex" : "male"
}, {
    "ownerid" : "33",
    "name" : "alex",
    "sex" : "male"
} ];

var cars = [ {
    "ownerid" : "11",
    "make" : "ford",
    "model" : "mustang"
}, {
    "ownerid" : "11",
    "make" : "honda",
    "model" : "civic"
}, {
    "ownerid" : "33",
    "make" : "toyota",
    "model" : "corolla"
} ];

var merge = function(array, array2, filter) {
    var result = [];
    for ( var i in array) {
        for (var j in array2) {
            var filtered = filter(array[i],array2[j]);
            if (filtered != null){
                result.push(filtered);
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
};
var result = merge(owners,cars,function(owner,car){
    if (owner.ownerid == car.ownerid){
        return {
            name : owner.name,
            model : car.model
        };
    }
    return null;
});
console.log('array',result);
```